# filter a dictionary by key less than some range of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this,

```
d = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}
```

Now I want to filter the dictionary where the key should be more than 1 and less than 4 so the dictionary will be,

```
d = {2:'b', 3:'c'}
```

I could do this using a for loop, iterating over all the keys. but the execution time will be more looking for some fastest way to do this more efficiently in pythonic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python dictionaries use hashes of their keys to efficiently lookup and store data. Unfortunately, that means that they don't allow you use the numeric properties of those keys to select data (the way you might be able to do using a slice to index a list).

So I think the best way to do what you want is probably just a dictionary comprehension that tests each key against your boundary values:

```
d = {key: value for key, value in d.items() if 1 < key < 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try below code:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if 1<k<4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic way would be to use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```py
{key: value for key, value in d.items() if 1 < key < 4}
```

It's readable enough: for each `key` and `value` in the `items` of the dictionary, keep those `key: value` pairs that have their `key`s between 1 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

More pythonic way would be a dictionary comprehension

```
d = {k: v for (k, v) in d.items() if k > 1 and k < 4}
```

If the efficiency is a bottleneck, you may want to try to use some tree based structure instead of a dictionary that is hash based.